# How to reuse Fortran modules without copying source or creating libraries

Tags: module, linker, fortran, intel-fortran, photran

I'm having trouble understanding if/how to share code among several Fortran projects without building libraries or duplicating source code.

I am using Eclipse/Photran with the Intel compiler (ifort) on a linux system, but I believe I'm having a bigger conceptual problem with modules than with the specific tools.

Here's a simple example: In ~/workspace/cow I have a source directory (src) containing cow.f90 (the PROGRAM) and two modules m_graze and m_moo in m_graze.f90 and m_moo.f90, respectively. This project builds and links properly to create the executable 'cow'. The executable and modules (m_graze.mod and m_moo.mod) are stored in ~/workspace/cow/Debug and object files are stored under ~/workspace/cow/Debug/src

Later, I create ~/workplace/sheep and have src/sheep.f90 as the program and src/m_baa.f90 as the module m_baa. I want to 'use m_graze, only: ruminate' in sheep.f90 to get access to the ruminate() subroutine. I could just copy m_graze.f90 but that could lead to code getting out of sync and doesn't take into account any dependencies m_graze might have. For these reasons, I'd rather leave m_graze in the cow project and compile and link sheep.f90 against it.

If I try to compile the sheep project, I'll get an error like:

```
error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [M_GRAZE]
```

Under Properties:Project References for sheep, I can select the cow project. Under Properties:Fortran Build:Settings:Intel Compiler:Preprocessor I can add ~/workspace/cow/Debug (location of the module files) to the list of include directories so the compiler now finds the cow modules and compiles sheep.f90. However the linker dies with something like:

```
Building target: sheep
Invoking: Intel(R) Fortran Linker
ifort -L/home/me/workspace/cow/Debug -o "sheep"  ./src/sheep.o
./src/sheep.o: In function `sheep':
/home/me/workspace/sheep/src/sheep.f90:11: undefined reference to `m_graze_mp_ruminate_'
```

This would normally be solved by adding libraries and library paths to the linker settings except there are no appropriate libraries to link to (this is Fortran, not C.)

The cow project was perfectly capable of compiling and linking together cow.f90, m_graze.f90 and m_moo.f90 into an executable. Yet while the sheep project can compile sheep.f90 and m_baa.f90 and can find the module m_graze.mod, it can't seem to find the symbols for m_graze even though all the requisite information is present on the system for it to do so.

It would seem to be an easy matter of configuration to get the linker portion of ifort to find the missing pieces and put them together but I have no idea what magic words need to be entered where in the Photran UI to make this happen.

I confess an utter lack of interest and competence in C and the C build process and I'd rather avoid the diversion of creating libraries (.a or .so) unless that's the only way to make this work.

Ultimately, I'm looking for a pure Fortran solution to this problem so I can keep a single copy of the source code and don't have to manually maintain a pile of custom Makefiles.

So can this be done?

Apologies if this has already been documented somewhere; Google is only showing me simple build examples, how to create modules, and how to link with existing libraries. There don't seem to be (m)any examples of code reuse with modules that don't involve duplicating source code.

---

### Edit

As respondents have pointed out, the .mod files are necessary but not sufficient; either object code (in the form of m_graze.o) or [static](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/win/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_create_stlib.htm) or [shared](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/lin/bldaps_for/lin/bldaps_create_shlib.htm) libraries must be specified during the linking phase. The .mod files describe the interface to the object code/library but both are necessary to build the final executable.

For an oversimplified toy problem such as this, that's sufficient to answer the question as posed.

In a larger project with more complex dependencies (in my case, 80+KLOC of F90 linking to the MKL version of LAPACK95), the IDE or toolchain may lack sufficient automatic or user-interface facilities to make sharing a single canonical set of source files a viable strategy. The choice seems to be between risking duplicate source files getting out of sync, giving up many of the benefits of an IDE (i.e. avoiding manual creation of make/CMake/SCons files), or, in all likelihood, both. While a revision control system and good code organization can help, it's clear that sharing a single canonical set of source files among projects is far from easy given the current state of Eclipse.

Comment: Where do you link with `m_graze.o`?

Comment: That appears to be the key. I'm not explicitly linking with m_graze.o and neither Photran nor the linker seem to have a way to to make this easy, especially if m_graze has a lot of dependencies. Not sure if there's a way to tell the linker "look here for *.o files and link against what you need" or if you have to explicitly list every dependency. It seems awfully tedious if it's the latter.

Comment: I can not help you with Photran projects, but i can recommend you to `SCons` instead of `make`. It's support of Fortran is very good and it is much easier to adjust than `make`. It does the dependency analysis automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question. You need to explicitly provide the object files at the linking stage. If there are too many object files, put them in a library (`.a` or `.so`). This part has nothing to do with C. Libraries are just containers of object files. This is what I usually do for my Fortran programs + `make`. `SCons` is good too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some background which I suspect you already know: Typically (including ifort) compiling the source code for a Fortran module results in two outputs - a "mod" file that contains a description of the Fortran entities that the module defines that the *compiler* needs to find whenever it sees a USE statement for the module, and object code for the *linker* that implements the procedures and variable storage, etc., that the module defines.

Your first error (the one you solved) is because the compiler couldn't find the mod file.

The second error is because the linker hasn't been told about the object code that implements the stuff that was in the source file with the module.  I'm not an Eclipse user by any means, but a brute force way of specifying that is just to add the object file (`xxxxx/Debug/m_graze.o`) as an additional linker option (Fortran Build > Settings, under Intel Fortran Linker > Command Line).   (Other tool chains have explicit "additional object file" properties for their link stage - there may well be a better way of doing this for the Intel chain.)

For more involved examples you would typically create a library out of the shared code.  That's not really C specific, the only Fortran aspect is that the libraries archive of object code needs to be provided alongside the mod files that the Fortran compiler generates.

Comment: Right, so by analogy .mod files act as C header files, describing the calling interface to the intermediate code (object files and libraries).

Comment: A better analogy to C header files is the Fortran source code containing the module.  The compiler produces the .mod file from that and uses it to "do its job", e.g., checking argument consistency between call and actual procedure.  The .mod files are compiler specific and can even change with compiler version ... unlike the source code from which they were created.  The .mod files are outside of the language standard.

Comment: Thanks; that explains the lack of general documentation on .mod files.  I've learned a lot in trying to resolve this question, and none of it bodes well for reliable software development. There seems to be no good way to avoid duplicating source files within Eclipse (or maybe any IDE.) :/

Comment: I don't know about the IDE aspect.  I use Fortran modules between several projects and don't duplicate the source code files. I just have the several compile commands use the same file.  What do you do for a C header file used by several projects?

Comment: There's no need to duplicate the source, or even the compilation step.  You simply need to provide a reference to the directory that contains the mod files and a reference to the object files.  If you have multiple object files, then bundling them together in a library simplifies this.  mod files are somewhat equivalent to pre-compiled header files in C.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the object code must be provided. E.g., when you install libnetcdf-dev in Debian (`apt-get install libnetcdf-dev`), there is a `/usr/include/netcdf.mod` file that is included.

You can now use all netcdf routines in your Fortran code. E.g.,

```
program main
use netcdf
...
end
```

but you'll have link to the netcdf shared (or static) library, i.e.,

```
gfortran -I/usr/include/ main.f90 -lnetcdff
```

However, as user MSB mentioned the mod file can only be used by gfortran that comes with the distribution (`apt-get install gfortran`). If you want to use any other compiler (even a different version that you may have installed yourself) then you'll have to build netcdf yourself using that particular compiler.

So creating a library is not a bad solution.